# collection delete by index

Tags: java, collections

Guys how will I use `remove(object);` to delete an element by the **id** inputted by the user. I don't know how to implement `indexOf(object);` since I have many variables in my arguments I cant do it like this `indexOf(id);`
`remove(indexOf(id));` Teach me how.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("ITEM MANAGEMENT");
        lineBreak(20, "*");
        System.out.println("[1] - Add Item");
        System.out.println("[2] - Delete Item");
        System.out.println("[3] - Edit Item");
        System.out.println("[4] - List All Items");
        System.out.println("[5] - View Item");
        System.out.println("[6] - Exit");
        lineBreak(20, "-");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice>> ");
        int choice = s.nextInt();
        int id;
        String name, des;
        float price;
        Item i;

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.print("INPUT ID: ");
                id = s.nextInt();
                s.nextLine(); //trap
                System.out.print("INPUT NAME: ");
                name = s.nextLine();
                System.out.print("INPUT DESCRIPTION: ");
                des = s.nextLine();
                System.out.print("INPUT PRICE: ");
                price = s.nextFloat();
                i = new Item(id,price,name,des);
                items.add(i);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("ENTER ID: ");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("ENTER ID: ");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%10s\n","ID","NAME","PRICE");
                lineBreak(20," -");
                for(Item item: items){
                    System.out.printf("%-10d%-10s%10.2f\n",item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice());
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("ENTER ID: ");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.exit(1);
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }

}

public static void lineBreak(int n, String ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(ch);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: have your equals method compare by the id

Comment: You'll have to use a loop of some kind and find the matching item with the same id

Comment: You could use something like `List<Item> results = items.stream().filter((Item t) -> { return t.getId() == id; }).collect(Collectors.toList());` which will return a `List` of `Item`'s whose id is equal to the query.  The result `List` should be 0 or more in size, but, you could simple use `items.removeAll(results);` to remove the elements in `results` from `items` ...

Comment: Too complex for me to understand haha. For example i inputed 123 for the id and apple for the name can i get the index of the integer 123? and then use it to items.remove(123); to remove the 123 apple?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

THIS IS WHAT IVE DONE TO COMPARE THE INPUTED ID TO THE ID'S IN THE OBJECTS.
IT WORKS!

```
                id = s.nextInt();
                for(Item itm: items){
                    if(id == itm.getId()){items.remove(itm);}
                }
```

Comment: You will get the `ConcurrentModificationException`  exception in this approach. **Java Collection classes are fail-fast which means that if the Collection will be changed while some thread is traversing over it.**

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Map`<Integer, Item>`** instead of **List** for storing the **Item** objects. In the **Map** You can fetch the **Item** by the given **Id** and delete the **Item** Object from the Map.

If you need to use **List** only, Then you need to iterate over the list, every time you delete an **Item** from the list. You can use the following piece of code for deleting the **Item** in the **List**. Given you have `getId()` method in the **Item** class.

```
Iterator<Item> itemIterator = items.iterator();
int id = s.nextInt();
while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
  Item item = itemIterator.next();
  if (item.getId() == id) {
    itemIterator.remove();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro i appreciate your answer it works but we cant use iterator we haven't learn that lesson yet in our java class but thanks.

Comment: I dont know either haha.

Comment: i got a solution :
                     id = s.nextInt();
                    for(Item itm: items){
                        if(id == itm.getId()){items.remove(itm);}
                    }

Comment: If you cannot use the `iterator`, then you can create another `List` with `Item` objects and later remove those objects from original `List` using `removeAll()` method.

Comment: Bro can you help me how will i say that if they enter existing id when adding new item the program will say that "This id is already exist and when deleting itll also say that "this id does not exist" if the inputed id does not exist same in editing. I need a function like that i cant figure how

Comment: You can use either `Set` or `Map` for this. Try something out. Then let me know.

Comment: I tried to use `HashMap` and `Set` it works i used `if(items.get(id)==null){printl("This id does not exist")}` but i want to make it as a function to make it clean the problem is i dont know how to pass the items to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Given your current implementation, you would need to loop over the list and find the `Item`(s) which have a matching `id`

Something like...

```
int deleteId = s.nextInt();
Iterator<Item> it = items.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Item next = it.next();
    if (next.getId() == deleteId) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Equally you could also take advantage of Java 8's stream support and do something like...

```
int deleteId = s.nextInt();
List<Item> results = items.stream().filter((Item t) -> { return t.getId() == deleteId; }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could then use the resulting `List` to remove all the elements in it from the `items` list...

```
items.removeAll(results);
```

*Another possibility

Is to find the first `Item` which matches the required id...

```
int deleteId = s.nextInt();
Item item = list.stream().filter(x -> 
    {
        return x.getId() == deleteId;
    })
.findFirst()
.get();
if (item != null) {
    items.remove(item);
}
```

Comment: its too complex for me to understand bro we did not tackle that lesson yet .Cant i get the index of the of the object using id only? for example indexOf(id); then that index will be use on remove.(index)? something simple like that hahaha

Comment: *"Cant i get the index of the of the object using id only?"* - Within your current implementation, you have to use a loop, `List` has no means by which it can search a property of your object